# How to refresh the start menu on Lubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, wine

Previously I installed WeChat on Wine but I uninstalled because it doesn't work very well. Although I uninstalled WeChat, the program still appears in the start menu. What should I do to remove the program from the start menu? I have already rebooted the computer but it still appears.

Here's a screenshot of my start menu:
[image]